# Path Id attribute is missing in WADL

Tags: java, rest, wadl

I am using jackson-jaxrs-1.5.7.jar for my rest web service. I am using custom CustomWADLGeneratorConfig to generate resource doc. The CustomWADLGeneratorConfig has the code as follows,

```
public List<WadlGeneratorDescription> configure() {
     List<WadlGeneratorDescription> ax = generator(WadlGeneratorResourceDocSupport.class).prop("resourceDocStream", "resourcedoc.xml").descriptions();
     return ax;
}
```

Wadl file has been generated successfully. But the resource class name is missing. After a long search in google I found that path id attribute describes the resource class name.
But in generated application.wadl file path has been found but id attribute (class name) is missing. How to get id attribute??

Comment: What is it being generated from?

Comment: @Donal Fellows - Through resource-doclet.jar I made ant build to produce resourcedoc.xml. In web.xml I have configure to load on startup for the class CustomWADLGeneratorConfig by extending WadlGeneratorConfig. So when the application is up it shows application.wadl file while hitting the corresponding URL. Resource path is available but id (Resource class name) is missing. I didn't used any grammar or xsd.